# Is That Wrong? - Store authentication Token in database, and for each request compare it to token saved in cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, cookies, formsauthenticationticket

**Issue:**

So I've been playing around with ASP.NET Forms Authentication, what I've done is that i basically created a User table with a Token columns to store Forms Authentication Token.

**Scenario:**

1. User enters his user name & password.
2. If user is found he gets authenticated.
3. Authentication Token is stored in database.
4. Encrypted Authenticated Token is stored in a cookie & sent to
   client.
5. When User Request a Method that requires authentication token saved
   in cookie gets decrypted and is compared with token stored in
   database.

**My Questions:**

1. Is that approach safe at all? Pros? Cons?
2. Can i use sessions with that approach so i would'd have to do a
   comparison with each request?

**Notes:**

1. Cookie expiration date set to 60 days from creation.
2. Used ORM is Rob Conery's Massive.

Comment: Why an *encrypted* token, out of interest?

Comment: mmm the reason behind that is if some how the db gets compromised, who ever gets the data won't be useful to him any way so it's just a security measure that i decided to take.

Comment: Well while that would seem as an easy take on handling a situation like this, However why not cut my loses? i mean imagine the hacker got a user's token & it's not encrypted now the user is screwed not me becuse simply i got a backup that i can restore every thing to order with but if the hacker got Un-Hashed sensetive data?

Comment: You should never store any sensitive data in the cookie anyway, the cookie should only ever be a reference to the sensitive data stored on the server.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that Microsoft have invested heavily in making sure that their systems are as secure as possible. This includes Forms Authentication; they wouldn't recommend it unless they were sure that, without the end user needing to perform any additional actions, it was secure by default.

I recall a question on SO recently where a user had decided that they would make their SHA-256 hash "more secure" by then hashing the result with MD5, and using that as their comparison. In this case, by adding "more security" they actually managed to significantly *decrease* the security of their system.

Therefore, I would personally avoid adding any complexity to Forms Authentication, and drop your idea of encrypting the token. There are sufficient resources available online and offline relating to securing it without adding your own little twist.

You mentioned the reason being in case "the db gets compromised" ... if that happens, then having encrypted cookies is neither here nor there, you're in serious trouble anyway. The chances are the attacker would also have access to your code and could use it to decrypt the cookies with minimal effort.

With regard to sessions, that depends on your application. If you're using the built-in Session in IIS, that's generally considered to be safe (the specific session in use is referenced by another cookie stored browser-side), as a hacker would have to have significant access to your server already in order to effect any compromise - and, again, accessing a user's session would be the least of your worries.